# when does wkhtmltopdf really fail

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm generating PDFs with `wkhtmltopdf`, which is awesome. However, sometimes the tool returns exit codes, but in a lot of cases, the PDF still seems to be generated properly.

How do I really know that `wkhtmltopdf` failed to do the job?

Examples:

http://www.egresadoutec.edu.sv/boletin_pdf_create.php?idbXwt=101 gives a 404, but in fact the whole page was created properly (albeit 12Mb).
http://www.anarchia.com/link_in_frame.php?link=7243 gives a 404 and indeed nothing was generated, but the file size is NOT 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very complicated issue actually. I sometimes want 404/500/503 pages to be rendered into a PDF normally. So what should the exit code then be? I think the exit code should be something like 2 just to inform me of what HTTP code the page returned but I still really do need the PDF to be rendered normally. I suspect that your actual issue is with the reasons for exit codes not being documented clearly, which is indeed true.

I created [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=1088) for this, but Antialize is a busy man so he might not have time for issues like this. I actually suspect that you are calling wkhtmltopdf from some wrapper you have created yourself and you are checking the exit code there. If you don't want a PDF produced if a URL returns something other than HTTP 2xx, I suggest that you check the URL yourself before calling wkhtmltopdf. Create a tool or use an exiting one to call that URL and check it's response. Not very expensive, simple and it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea - i'll add it as a first step and do a check on the returned filesize as well. Maybe I'll somehow be able to check if the PDF is empty as well - even though the filesize is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXITCODE     EXPLANATION
```

```
0            All OK
1            PDF generated OK, but some request(s) did not return HTTP 200
2            Could not something something
X            Could not write PDF: File in use
Y            Could not write PDF: No write permission
Z            PDF generated OK, but some JavaScript requests(s) timeouted
A            Invalid arguments provided
B            Could not find input file(s)
C            Process timeout
```

when on error code 1 or Z, it doesn't really fail. It creates the PDF. Ideally it should've been a warning.

Comment: Could not something something... this is about the most programmer-ish error statement I've read in a long time... :-D

Answer (score -1):

It is just a permission issue, kindly check the user permission you have on this file "wkhtmltopdf" and run accordingly or you can change it.

```
[root@localhost ~]#ls -l wkhtmltopdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xyz xyz 11068596 May  3 15:59 wkhtmltopdf
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]#su - xyz

[xyz@localhost ~]$ ./wkhtmltopdf
```

(you will get executable output of this file wkhtmltopdf.)

-Jonus Joseph